# how to make the date appear completely in vuejs-datepicker (z-index)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs-datepicker

I have a `vuejs-datepicke` component in v-server-table component which is in `collapse element`

`div.collapse > v-server-table.test-table > span > div.form-group > datepicker`

```
<div :class="{ 'show' : (wheel.id == defaultOpenedWheel || searchKey !== null)}" class="collapse"
   data-parent="#accordion"
   role="tabpanel"
   v-bind:aria-labelledby="'heading-'+index" v-bind:id="'collapse-'+index">
<v-server-table :columns="columnCompetences"
   class="test-table"
   :options="options"
   :show-pagination="false"
   @loaded="onLoaded"
   v-bind:ref="'wheel_'+wheel.id"
   v-bind:url="'/api/competences?wheelId='+wheel.id+'&querySearch='+searchKey+'&memberId='+memberId">
<span slot="target_date" slot-scope="{row}">
   <span v-if="rowToShow !== 'row'+row.id">{{formDate(row.target_date)}}</span>
   <div class="form-group" v-if="rowToShow === 'row'+row.id">
      <datepicker :format="customDateFormat" :input-class="'form-control'"
         v-model="updateRow.target_date"></datepicker>
      <small class="form-text  text-danger"
         v-if="formErrors !== null && formErrors.target_date!==undefined"> {{formErrors.target_date[0]}} </small>
   </div>
</span>
```

the problem : the datepicker is not completely shown (z-index problem I thinks) and I must to scroll-down !

[image]

Comment: I am not sure whether this work due to o working example of your code but you can try setting `.vdp-datepicker__calendar {    position: fixed;    top: auto;}` try setting `fixed` position rather then `absolute` with `top:auto`

Comment: I posted it as an answer to help others, please accept that  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add this to your scoped styles:

```
<style scoped >
>>> .vdp-datepicker__calendar {
  position: fixed;
}
// Your other styles..
 </style>
```

Or if you are using SCSS:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
::v-deep .vdp-datepicker__calendar {
  position: fixed;
}
// Your other styles..
</style>
```